# multiple paths for include_erts in config.exs

Tags: erlang, elixir

I have config.exs file and inside it I want to set path for include_erts. But this path varies depending on env in which my job is running. It should be different path for normal case and different when running inside docker container. Is it possible to set if/else (if directory exists) in config.exs?

I must add that I'm not elixir expert.

EDIT 1:
I wrote:
`set include_erts: cond do`
                         `File.exists?("/path/to/file/1") -> "/path/to/file/1"`
                         `File.exists?("/path/to/file/2") -> "/path/to/file/2"`
                         `true -> IO.puts(:stderr, "No proper file found")`
                       `end`
but I get error:
`13:54:00 ** (Mix.Releases.Config.LoadError) could not load release config rel/config.exs`
`13:54:00     ** (CompileError) nofile:21: undefined function set/2`
`13:54:00     (distillery) expanding macro:`  `Mix.Releases.Config.environment/2`
`13:54:00     nofile:19: (file)`
`13:54:00 [CI/back-end]   error: [+04:09] Error in elixir build.`

EDIT 2 (RESOLVED):
This works for me:
  `cond do`
    `File.exists?("/path/to/file/1") ->  set include_erts: "/path/to/file/1"`
    `File.exists?("/path/to/file/2") ->  set include_erts: "/path/to/file/2"`
    `true ->                             IO.puts(:stderr, "No proper path")`
  `end`

Comment: `config.exs` is a regular [tag:elixir] file. You might write any valid code there.